# SoapUI - How to connect database and prepare data before load test?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, groovy, soapui, load-testing

Recently I've discovered that you can make a JDBC request Test Step in SoapUI ([doc 1](https://www.soapui.org/jdbc/testing-jdbc-databases.html), [doc 2](https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/working-with-scripts.html)). And I have a load test that fails under certain conditions, i.e. I need to manually execute SQL script in order to prepare data each time before I run this load test.

I'm not sure that it's possible, but if it is, how can I automate my initialization step?

ps. If I simply add JDBC Request test step to the load test then this step executes multiple times and this is not what I want. I think I need to query database from setup script:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Possible, Setup Script will be run before test is executed - for example you can set a groovy script like:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

// db connection 
def DBurl = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@11.111.1.11:1521:SID'
def DBuser = 'user'
def DBpassword = 'password'
def DBdriver = 'oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource'
def DBsql = Sql.newInstance(DBurl, DBuser, DBpassword, DBdriver)


// your sql
try{
DBsql.execute('''
[SQL U WANT TO EXECUTE]
''' ) 
} catch (Exception e) {
log.error  e.getMessage()
}
```